Puzzling Kal Vachomer in Pirkei Avot
In chapter 6:3 of Pirkei Avot there is an interesting kal vachomer in which we learn that we are supposed to treat someone with honour even if we just learn one small thing from them from David HaMelech:

הַלּוֹמֵד מֵחֲבֵרוֹ פֶּרֶק אֶחָד אוֹ הֲלָכָה אַחַת אוֹ פָסוּק אֶחָד
אוֹ דִבּוּר אֶחָד אוֹ אֲפִלּוּ אוֹת אַחַת, צָרִיךְ לִנְהוֹג בּוֹ
כָבוֹד, שֶׁכֵּן מָצִינוּ בְדָוִד מֶלֶךְ יִשְׂרָאֵל, שֶׁלֹּא לָמַד
מֵאֲחִיתֹפֶל אֶלָּא שְׁנֵי דְבָרִים בִּלְבָד, קְרָאוֹ רַבּוֹ אַלּוּפוֹ
וּמְיֻדָּעוֹ, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (תהלים נה) וְאַתָּה אֱנוֹשׁ כְּעֶרְכִּי
אַלּוּפִי וּמְיֻדָּעִי. וַהֲלֹא דְבָרִים קַל וָחֹמֶר, וּמַה דָּוִד
מֶלֶךְ יִשְׂרָאֵל, שֶׁלֹּא לָמַד מֵאֲחִיתֹפֶל אֶלָּא שְׁנֵי דְבָרִים
בִּלְבַד קְרָאוֹ רַבּוֹ אַלּוּפוֹ וּמְיֻדָּעוֹ, הַלּוֹמֵד מֵחֲבֵרוֹ
פֶּרֶק אֶחָד אוֹ הֲלָכָה אַחַת אוֹ פָסוּק אֶחָד אוֹ דִבּוּר אֶחָד אוֹ
אֲפִלּוּ אוֹת אַחַת, עַל אַחַת כַּמָּה וְכַמָּה שֶׁצָּרִיךְ לִנְהוֹג
בּוֹ כָבוֹד. וְאֵין כָּבוֹד אֶלָּא תוֹרָה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (משלי ג)
כָּבוֹד חֲכָמִים יִנְחָלוּ, (משלי כח) וּתְמִימִים יִנְחֲלוּ טוֹב,
וְאֵין טוֹב אֶלָּא תוֹרָה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (משלי ד) כִּי לֶקַח טוֹב
נָתַתִּי לָכֶם תּוֹרָתִי אַל תַּעֲזֹבוּ:
One who learns from his fellow one chapter, or one halakhah, or one
verse, or one word, or even one letter, is obligated to treat him with
honor; for so we find with David, king of Israel, who learned from
Ahitophel no more than two things, yet called him his master, his
guide and his beloved friend, as it is said, “But it was you, a man
mine equal, my guide and my beloved friend” (Psalms 55:14). Is this
not [an instance of the argument] “from the less to the greater” (kal
vehomer)? If David, king of Israel who learned from Ahitophel no more
than two things, nevertheless called him his master, his guide and his
beloved friend; then in the case of one who learns from his fellow one
chapter, or one halakhah, or one verse, or one word, or even one
letter, all the more so he is under obligation to treat him with
honor. And “honor’” means nothing but Torah, as it is said, “It is
honor that sages inherit” (Proverbs 3:35). “And the perfect shall
inherit good” (Proverbs 28:10), and “good” means nothing but Torah, as
it is said, “For I give you good instruction; do not forsake my Torah”
(Proverbs 4:2).

What kind of Kal Vachomer is this? I understand pshat that if David was a king and yet he praised someone when they taught him something but that’s exactly the point…he is the king, so obviously if someone was able to teach him something (or any king, as long as their a humble king) you would honour them. Meaning to say if you want to teach Ploni that he should honour others you can’t teach me from a king because a king is at the top, so if someone now comes and can teach him something, ok wow big deal I need to show you honour (kind of like if you have the most gifted mathematician in the world, and he’s stuck on a problem and then a little kid solves it, for sure he would honour him because someone who goes above whose on top deserves honour). But for Ploni, how is he to relate? He’s not on top, so fine David praised Achitophel because David was on top and someone went above him, but that’s not a proof that I need to honour someone (my focus is on the kal vachomer, for sure you need to honour them but I don’t understand how this logic works for it)
